# Creating a image viewing canvas with pan and zoom and user interaction support

Tags: java, image, zooming, affinetransform, panning

I'm creating a program similar to Adobe Illustrator but much simpler and generates code rather than an image.

My issue I'm having is AffineTransform not working correctly for me. Most likely because of misuse. Yes, I know there are many AffineTransform threads, but they do not my answer my question.

Currently I'm trying to use three variables (scale, centerX, centerY) to control the viewing of the image. The centerX and centerY are relative to the image, not the screen cordinates. Their purpose is to make zooming in and out to be from the center of the JPanel rather than the top left corner.

I've gotten a few different tries to be VERY close, but not accurate enough for what I'm doing. After I get this accomplished, I have no idea how to handle user interaction, because AfflineTransform.createInverse() throws an NoninvertibleTransformException. Advice on this would be nice too.

I've tried so many didn't configurations, but with no luck. Here's my last approach at it to maybe give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
    private BufferedImage image;
private boolean loadingImage;
private double scale = 1;
private double centerX = 0;
private double centerY = 0;
private boolean disableDrag = false;
private boolean disableZoom = false;
private AffineTransform affineTransform;

private AffineTransform createAffineTransfomation() {
    affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
    affineTransform.translate(
            (centerX - (image.getWidth() / 2)) * scale,
            (centerY  - (image.getHeight() / 2)) * scale
            );
    affineTransform.scale(scale, scale);
    return affineTransform;
}
```

I hope I explained myself well enough. This AffineTransform stuff has gotten me so confused I can hardly explain what I'm trying to do anymore.

Comment: You're AffineTransform object was created without parameters, I believe its because you need to pass the appropriate information to the object so it can be inverted.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createInverse()

use the getDeterminate() method to check before inverting.

Comment: Well I can't really test any of the inverse operations until I get the AffineTransform right in the first place. The determinate is calculated by multiplying certain values in the matrix. Unfortunately, I would have to apply a shear or rotation to keep those values from being 0 (the cause of the exception). I'm stumped...

Comment: *"I hope I explained myself well enough."*  Not sure, didn't read it, but searched for a '?' and did not locate one.  Do you have a question?